# include script that depends on modernizr?

Tags: wp-register-script

first time i am trying to include script to wordpress,but
after several hours reading wordpress codex and answers all over the web ,i still dont success to link the script to modernizr,
they both show in the head of the page as if they were registerd correctly but the script still ignores modernizr.

here is the code in function.php

```
function childtheme_script_manager() {
wp_register_script('new_service', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/modernizr.custom.79639.js', array('jquery'), true, true);
wp_enqueue_script('new_service');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'childtheme_script_manager');

function twentyfourteen_child_scripts() {
     wp_enqueue_script('twentyfourteen_child_scripts',   get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.swatchbook.js');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentyfourteen_child_scripts' );
```

Comment: Seems to me that if the scripts were loaded correctly in the header or footer then the problem is not with the script registration. Have you tried to use the browser debug to look for JS errors? First thing I typically do after adding a script and it's not working, it's to add an alert("Test") to the top of the JS file to see if it's being loaded correctly. If the alert works, but not the rest then the problem is with the script.

Comment: yes of course i put console.log in both scripts and yes they are being loaded ,so what could be the reason that in my local server/computer its working but not inside wordpress?

Comment: Hard-coded urls? Paths inside the script? Hard to tell without looking at the page or the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume these are child theme scripts because of your function name:

```
twentyfourteen_child_scripts()
```

When loading scripts from your child themes functions file you should use:

```
wp_enqueue_script( '$handle', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/js/filename.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0' );
```

Or use

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_add_modernizr_scripts' );

function child_add_modernizr_scripts() {
wp_register_script('modernizr', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/modernizr.js', false, '1.0', true );

wp_enqueue_script( 'modernizr' );
}
```

Another potential problem maybe the file names are invalid for some reason.

```
get_template_directory_uri()
```

Applies to parent themes.

Comment: about get_template_directory_uri() , is it ok to write something like this instead ?  --->               get_template_directory_uri().'-child/js/the-script.js');

Comment: so how to show/write that the script depends on modernizr ? like this ? ---------> wp_enqueue_script('the-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/modernizr.js', false, '1.0', true );

Comment: In your child theme, you use one of my 2 answers. Parent themes use get_template_directory_uri()

Comment: why is  including the scripts in the head is actually not enough in wordpress? why do we need  dependencies ?

Comment: thank you very much that did the trick -->  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() for theme child files ill remember that:)